# How to remove page tab from Facebook pages?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We can offer to the user an easy way to add a page tab to their pages with:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&display=popup&next=YOUR_URL
```

ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/

---

Is there an easy way to remove page tabs? Hopefully through Graph API or a link like the showed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are 2 options that I know of:

1. The Page's admin user can either remove the tab manually:

   1. by clicking the "x" next to the tab in the sidebar
   2. going into the 'Edit Page' options and removing the App
2. You can use the [Page Graph API /tabs object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs) to issue a `DELETE` HTTP request to `graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs/APP_ID` *

*Your app will need the `manage_pages` permission to get the [Page Access Token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens) to make this API call.

Comment: +1 Your point 2 seems promising. I'll check it and feedback. THX

Comment: Doesn´t work in here, there is no X in tabs, and there is no App in the Edit Page! And also, when I do a get to the graph api tabs, It shows only two app, Likes and reviews, and also I cannot remove them ! I removed the photos app using graph but it didn´t changes any thing! Facebook crap